# SQL Query - Select Customers over a certain age

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to `SELECT` customers who are over the age of 65, and also have a balance greater than 5000.

I can not figure out how to successfully calculate their age in my `WHERE` clause.

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    Customer.ID, Customer.lastName, Customer.firstName
FROM 
    CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN 
    has ON has.ID = CUSTOMER.ID
INNER JOIN 
    Account ON Account.ACCNUMBER = has.ACCNUMBER
WHERE 
    Account.BALANCE > 5000 
    AND ((DATEDIFF(DAY, CUSTOMER.DATEOFBIRTH, GETDATE()) / 365.25) > 65)
ORDER BY 
    CUSTOMER.LASTNAME;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (Some product specific SQL there...)

Comment: For Postgres: `where age(CUSTOMER.DATEOFBIRTH) > interval '65' year`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,
That is why I love postgreSQL most in the databases I use:) Others are not as advanced as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Age is the easiest part, just add 65 years to DateOfBirth and check if it is in past.
Your query has a suspect inner join. Is it all 1-to-1? You would know its details but at least I would write that part as an exists query:

```
SELECT  ID, lastName, firstName
FROM    CUSTOMER
WHERE   DATEADD(YEAR, 65, DATEOFBIRTH) < getdate() AND
        EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   has
                 INNER JOIN Account ON Account.ACCNUMBER = has.ACCNUMBER
                 WHERE  has.ID = CUSTOMER.ID AND
                        Account.BALANCE > 5000 )
ORDER BY LASTNAME;
```

Oh you were not using MS SQL server but Oracle, wish you specified that in your question:

```
SELECT  ID, lastName, firstName
FROM    CUSTOMER
WHERE   ADD_MONTHS(DATEOFBIRTH, 65*12) < SYSDATE AND
        EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   has
                 INNER JOIN Account ON Account.ACCNUMBER = has.ACCNUMBER
                 WHERE  has.ID = CUSTOMER.ID AND
                        Account.BALANCE > 5000 )
ORDER BY LASTNAME;
```

Comment: Thank you @Cetin Basoz ! Sorry, I didn't realise the difference was so great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    Customer.ID, Customer.lastName, Customer.firstName
FROM 
    CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN 
    has ON has.ID = CUSTOMER.ID
INNER JOIN 
    Account ON Account.ACCNUMBER = has.ACCNUMBER
WHERE 
    Account.BALANCE > 5000 
    AND Customer.DateOfBirth <= DATEADD(YEAR, -65, SYSDATETIME()) 
ORDER BY 
    CUSTOMER.LASTNAME;
```

`DATEADD` subtract 65 years from the current system date (from "Today"), and then selects all those customers with a `DateOfBirth` that's *before* that cut-off date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @marc_s ! The above code gives me an error saying "DATED": invalid identifier. I am using SQL Developer if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server database you can use this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE 
    Account.balance > 5000
    AND Customer.dateofbirth <= DATEADD(yy, -65, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks @fabulaspb ! The above code gave me the following error - "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier. I am using SQL Developer if that makes any difference?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: DateDiff(yy, ...) would ignore the months which may be important on a legal retirement system.

Comment: @fabulaspb it is a custom one for my course tute - Would that be why it isn't working?

Comment: I meant datediff(yy, ...) wouldn't even work on MS SQL server. It ignores the month, day parts and simply do a math on year part. IOW someone born on 2015-12-31 is 1 year old today  according to datediff(yy, ...). If this was a calculation say for medical administration then baby would be in serious trouble.

Comment: @CetinBasoz yes I've mind this problem and rewrote my query.